# My RegEx is losing data, any way to correct?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, logging

I'm attempting to parse the following log format; there are two fields I need, both are denoted in the following format:

```
"LOGTYPE":"LOGDATA"
```

There is a really long one under the message column but I have already worked out parsing it, just have to be able to isolate it first.

My current expressions leave out the last log (Hostname), or lose some of the formatting if I correct it to include Hostname. I can always correct the data loss after the regex query but would prefer to keep the code concise if at all possible.

**Here are my regex attempts:**

Loses Hostname log

```
/("\w*"):(.*?),/gi
```

Incorrect end formatting on the Message, ChannelID, Hostname sections

```
/("\w*"):(.*?)[,}]/gi
```

**Sample Log:**

> {"EventTime":"2018-02-01 12:00:00","EventType":"WARNING","EventID":1,"SourceName":"PrintfLogger","ProcessID":1234,"ThreadID":1234,"Message":"123456789 : TESTING CurlPublishPoint: Published http://host.sample.com/sample/test/folder275492/123456789_set_11/test.ts (0 bytes) in 2203.000000 ms (total time) from :0 to 11.22.3.444:0 : seqNumber 99101 : DNS Time : 0.000000 s : Connect Time 0.000000 s : Upload Speed 0.000000 B/s : Longer than RetryLimit false : Segment Lead Time 3084 ms: cURL ErrorCode 28 : cURL error Timeout was reached : HTTP Code 0 : Success false : Attempt 1 : Type TS : File Size 123456 : Bytes Remaining 123456 : MediaId Service_Data_3 : Publish Lead Time 1234 ms : Id 0 : CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT 123456 : Retry Limit 9000 ms : cURL Remote IP : Low Speed Time 3 : cURL URL http://11.2.3.444/sample/test/1518718912_set_34/test_123456_78901.ts : Session Count 634 : Thread Id 4172 : MD5 123456789ABCDEFG1234567890HIJK1L : Latency 0.000000s : ChId:{A1B2C3D4-E5F6-G7H8-I9J0-K1L2M3N4O5P6}","Opcode":"Log","ChannelId":"{A1B2C3D4-E5F6-G7H8-I9J0-K1L2M3N4O5P6}","EventDesc":"Printf","TaskDesc":"Package","Hostname":"A11B2-1234A56"}

Comment: I think you're better of parsing the log as a json.

Comment: Still pretty new to all of this so excuse my entry-level questions :P

This is a component of a script which pulls down logs from a central logging server formatted as a string, am I correct in the assumption that I can just pass the string value I recieve into a JSON format, and then parse those in an array of JSONs?

Or would there be a more direct approach?

Comment: the string looks to be properly formatted json. it appears each log entry is a valid json, so you should be able to use `json.loads` for processing them

Comment: Ahh, okay thank you. I'll look into the json object / methods! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments by Haleemur Ali, this data is a properly formatted JSON. He pointed me in the right direction by suggesting I handle it as one.

Using the following function will convert the string to a JSON object, which can be handled much more easily.

```
logJSON = json.loads(inputstring)
```

I used the following video to familiarize myself with JSON handling in Python prior to reading the documentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N6a-VLBa2I

Comment: This won't really help newcomers who are struggling with similar problems. Please post at least a sketch of your actual code.

Comment: Hope that is a bit better! :)